# How can I make and extend a vertical line upwards in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, format, text-decorations

I want to create a vertical line that extends upwards instead of both down and up if that makes sense. I think I need a  to create it, but after that, how do I customize it to extend up and not extend down?

[Picture of line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQZ0s.png)

This is what I have so far right now. I need it to extend up to the first icon, but not lower than the last icon. The line is kind of contained inside a container, and the first icon is part of the parent container which is a row in a MUIx datagrid row.

```
position: absolute;
width: 1px;
background-color: black;
z-index: 1;
left: calc(50px / 2);
top: 1px;
height: auto;
bottom: 33px;
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide at least an image of what you're trying to accomplish here. Are you trying to get a line has its height extend past the box containing it on the top edge?

Comment: Yeah, this is a "a picture is worth 1000 words" kind of situation.  I'm very curious what a "line that extends up but not down" will turn out to be.

Comment: @SteveE Sorry about that, I've included an image